# Drop down list of universities

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

Part of a website (its a PHP/mysql based social network) I am working on includes a profile section that requires the user to select what University they are currently based in. A simple drop down box with all the possible university options makes sense. However, my website is not based for a particular country hence making the list enormous. Is there an easier way of doing this that doesn't involve a drop down box? A simple text field would be OK but my problem with this is that different users might spell out their university name different hence making the search a little more difficult.

Comment: can you use an auto-completion control? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Do you have every university in the world in your database?? If not then text field and decent matching algorithm is your answer

Comment: Maybe you can let them search a country first, but I think more friendly is to just let the user type the name and search for that. Perhaps you can filter out some stop words (like school, university and any translations and abbreviations for that, since they are usually not part of the name).

Answer (score 1):

I know your answer says that you will use only one dropdown, but you can also make a dropdown populate from another dropdown using JQuery/Ajax. This way the user does not have to reload the page, and it may be less complicated than an auto complete if you cannot find or program a suitable one.

You would use:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

and traverse the DOM such as in this example:
http://devingredients.com/2011/05/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-with-jquery/

[image: dual dropdowns]

Check out this previous answer for more specific code and instructions on populating a drop down list with jquery and ajax and php: [Trying to populate a drop down list with jquery and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979369/trying-to-populate-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery-and-ajax)

It is a common method used in PHP programming, and allowing a user to select a country first may mean less confusion if the college has campuses in many different countries.

Comment: Have not downvoted as you are new but this does not answer the question specifics

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say the question specifics? Please give me a concrete example. This way I can improve or delete the answer.

Comment: Well this isnt a good question! but it certainly does not mention linked dropdowns, and you dont mention why they would help him in any way.